# how to save html page in pdf format include contents like text, image using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, html5-canvas

I want to save HTML page into pdf format, Im using jsPDF script this works only in text format but if any URL or image in this page, script not working.

Comment: I think jsPDF will be a better option for your case . 
 [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOMPDF will be useful for HTML to pdf and it will support for images and links also.
Please go through https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

Comment: You also have Html2pdf, it's almost the same thing as DOMPDF.
http://html2pdf.fr/